# Batch: Specific Line to variable

Tags: variables, batch-file

I am trying to copy a specific line out of a file to a variable in a batch file.
Basically I need to copy line 6 of a file and make it into a variable.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you try to do, and what happened when you tried it?  Your question isn't yet in the scope of what Stack Overflow handles.  For example, what language are you trying to use and what did you write in it?

Comment: I tried just copying the whole thing into a variable and trying to remove specific other lines, but that didn't work. It's batch/MS-DOS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "skip=5delims=" %%i in (filename) do set "var=%%i"&goto nextline
:nextline
```

Should do the job.

Comment: Magoo, your code will work independly of the existence of previous blank lines. `skip` skips lines, blank or not.